# Rewrite jQuery Ajax call in AngularJS

Tags: ajax, jquery, angularjs

Is there an AngularJS equivalent call to this jQuery ajax POST, with `contentType` and `setRequestHeader`?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/songs",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems");
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http) or [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) service. In the $http doc you can see the section on **Setting HTTP Headers** to set the SOAPAction and the default content type will be set to json already (though you should be able to override that as well).

This might get you started and I'd be interested to see other answers for a better way because this seems limited.

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['SOAPAction'] = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems';
});

function myController($http) {
    var data = { 'value1': 1, 'value2': 2 };

    $http.post('/songs', data).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Based on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/X00TD-QnGCc/discussion) I don't believe you can set the headers differently for each call but it looks like a [change](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/965) might be coming to the $resource service that will allow it.

**Update:** Must have missed it in the documentation but you can most definitely set different actions per call using `$http` per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876777/angularjs-set-http-header-for-one-request) like this:

```
var data = { 'value1': 1, 'value2': 2 };

$http.post('/songs', data, {headers: {'SOAPActions': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems'}})
    .success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```