# angular $http GET request with authorization token header

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to replicate this curl using angular $http.get,

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:3000/posts -H 'Authorization: Token token="1111"'
```

but I am not sure how to properly set the angular header

this is how I tried it,

```
    app.controller('newsCtrl', function($http, $scope){
      $scope.news =[];
      $http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts.json', {
        headers: {"Authorization": "Token[token]=1111"}).success(function(response){
        console.log(response)
      })
    })
```

So how do I properly set the header?

Thank you
ps: I am not using Basic authentication.

Comment: Why are you using `Token[token]=1111` in Angular and not `Authorization: Token token="1111"`?

Comment: That is my question actually, how to properly write the header.  I tried this as well, `$http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts.json', {
    headers: {"Authorization: Token token=1111"})` but still not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set HTTP header for one request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876777/set-http-header-for-one-request)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the Authorization header to contain `Token token="1111"`, then this should work. It looks like your brackets were not matching up also.

```
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts.json', {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Token token="1111"'
    }
  }).success(function(response){
    console.log(response)
  });
```

Comment: Sorry for my question but doesn't this approach expose your API key (using developer tools)?

Comment: Yes, it would. Depending on your use case, that may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: @AnidMonsur could you elaborate on why this is exposing the token?  Is that still true if one uses TLS?