# How to send an HTTP request with a header parameter?

Tags: javascript, json, api, http, callback

I'm very new to javascript and web programming in general and I need some help with this. I have an HTTP request that I need to send through javascript and get need to store the output in a variable. I tried using just the call url:

```
https://api.fantasydata.net/nfl/v2/JSON/PlayerSeasonStats/2015
```

But it returns an authentication error because I didn't send my API key and it doesn't show me how to do it just in the URL. The API key is listed as a header and not a paramater and I'm not sure what to do with that. I tried using the XMLHttpRequest() class but I'm not quite sure I understand exactly what it does nor could I get it to work.

The actual HTTP Request

```
GET https://api.fantasydata.net/nfl/v2/JSON/PlayerSeasonStats/2015 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.fantasydata.net
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
```

I just need to figure out how to send that request along with the key and how to store the JSON doc it returns as a variable in javascript.

EDIT: This is what I have so far:

```
function testingAPI(){
var key = "8a1c6a354c884c658ff29a8636fd7c18";
httpGet("https://api.fantasydata.net/nfl/v2/JSON/PlayerSeasonStats/2015",key    );
alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
var x = 0;
}

function httpGet(theUrl,key)
{
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",key);
xmlHttp.send( null );
return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your code sending request?

Comment: Sorry, just added it!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If it says the API key is listed as a header, more than likely you need to set it in the `headers` option of your http request.  Normally something like this :

```
headers: {'Authorization': '[your API key]'}
```

Here is an example from another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876777/set-http-header-for-one-request)

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '[the-target-url]', headers: {
  'Authorization': '[your-api-key]'}
});
```

**Edit :**  Just saw you wanted to store the response in a variable. In this case I would probably just use AJAX.  Something like this :

```
$.ajax({ 
   type : "GET", 
   url : "[the-target-url]", 
   beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '[your-api-key]');},
   success : function(result) { 
       //set your variable to the result 
   }, 
   error : function(result) { 
     //handle the error 
   } 
 });
```

I got this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call) and I'm at work so I can't test it at the moment but looks solid

**Edit 2:** Pretty sure you should be able to use this line :

```
headers: {'Authorization': '[your API key]'},
```

instead of the `beforeSend` line in the first edit.  This may be simpler for you

Comment: So that makes sense,  but how would I incorporate this in my javascript file?

Comment: Was editing my answer as your commented, hope that can clear some things up.  You can just place that AJAX request wherever you need to get the information in your JS file.  I personally like to have them in their own functions

Comment: I'll try it now! Thank you so much

Comment: instead of using `beforeSend` pretty sure you can just use the headers line at the top of my answer.  That may be easier and I will add it to the bottom of the answer as well

Answer (score 11):

With your own **Code** and a **Slight Change** withou jQuery,

```
function testingAPI(){ 
    var key = "8a1c6a354c884c658ff29a8636fd7c18"; 
    var url = "https://api.fantasydata.net/nfl/v2/JSON/PlayerSeasonStats/2015";
    console.log(httpGet(url,key)); 
}


function httpGet(url,key){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",key);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

**Thank You**

Comment: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.