# How to send Authorization in http headers in Angular.Js

Tags: angularjs, rest, chat, openfire

I'm developing an chat application using angular js and Openfire xmpp server.
I need to send call Openfire REST api from angular js.

How to send Authorization in http headers in Angular.Js.

Comment: See related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876777/set-http-header-for-one-request

Comment: I am getting the following info in headers. Request URL:localhost:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users Request Method:OPTIONS Status Code:401 Unauthorized I dint see the "Authorization" key value in the Request headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the REST API and AngularJS with, if you use the shared key:

```
$http.get('http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users', {
  headers: {'Authorization': 'y0rSharedKey'}
});
```

or with the base64 encoded 'username:password' like:

```
$http.get('http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users', {
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}
});
```