# In Angular need to set Authorisation header before transfer

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$scope.downloadPDF = function (docId) {
        //Need the code to add the authorisation header before transfer
        var pdfURL = $rootScope.genericApiurl + 'servicetype/pdfDocument?docId=' + docId;
        $window.location.href = pdfURL;
    }
```

Tried setting $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic' + authdata; but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `$window.location.href` the browser will make HTTP request, not your code. So you cannot add authentication header for it.

I suggest that you could use a parameter `?token=auth_token` instead.

**There is another suggesstion (more secure):**
You can generate a download token for each PDF file which will contain expire time and some information, the token will be encrypted. In server side (your api), you will get the token then you can decrypt it and check this token is valid or invalid. If it's valid you will return a FileContent type from your api.

E.g. yourdomain.com/api/document/aaa-bbb-ccc/download/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy‌​yyyyyyy

With:
**xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy**: token
**aaa-bbb-ccc**: documentId

Comment: This has to be through Authorization header only, I can not transfer my token as a parameter or else I need to change the web api just for this call, which is not a good option, this also has security issues. Please share if you have any other options like using $resource etc.

Comment: Oh, I understand your situation now. There is another option that you will generate a download token for each file pdf which will contain expire time and some information, the token will be encrypted. In server side (your api), you will get the token then you can decrypt it and check this token is valid or not. If valid you will return a FileContent type from your api. E.g. yourdomain.com/document/aaa-bbb-ccc/download/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy: token; aaa-bbb-ccc: documentId.

Comment: Yes you got the point now, I just implemented this approach and its works like wonder. I will accept this as my solution, if you can elaborate this in your answer a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following snippet

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'www.google.com/someapi', headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}
});
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11876907/2134604

Comment: PDF is not getting downloaded in this approach. Thats why I opted for $window.location.href. Do I have any feature available in $window to do this or may be $resource?

Comment: then you can use params options to append your header

Comment: Can you please share with me an example?