# Angular $response GET request removes content type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, http-headers, content-type

This is my Resource

```
this.users = $resource(AppConstants.baseUrl);
```

This is my interceptor

```
return {
      request : function(config){

        if(blackList.indexOf(config.url.index) != -1){ //Skip API which does not demand JSON type
          config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";  
        }

        //Delete content type for GET request
        if (!config.data) {
          console.log('Setting content type')
          delete config.headers['Content-Type'];
          config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;charset=utf-8";  
        }
        console.log(config)

        return config;
      },

      response : function(response){
        return response;
      }
    };
```

Now, whenever I make a GET request, the Content-Type is duly removed from Request. I even passed dummy data but still no luck. Unfortunately, my REST API demands `Content-Type` to be mentioned explicitly.

What am I missing!

Comment: you can try using http://stackoverflow.com/a/11876907/1306308

Comment: I want to use resources as its more elegant  and tidy when compared to $http

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Its the infamous angular format, if the data is null, remove the Content-Type

The work around would be , change the HTTP Interceptor. Referring to the interceptor in my question, I added one line

```
 if (!config.data) {
          console.log('Setting content type')
          delete config.headers['Content-Type'];
          config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;charset=utf-8";  
          config.data = { dummy : "dummy" }; //Send a dummy data so that your content-type is retained
        }
```