# HTTP Basic Authentication GET request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, basic-authentication

I have one GET endpoint.

It has HTTP Basic Authentication enabled. I want to create a GET request to the given end point.

```
https://example.com/api GET 

User Name :- admin

Password :- admin
```

My Code :-

```
$scope.listData = function() {
  $http.get('https://example.com/api').then(function(response) {
    $scope.items = response.data;
  });
}
```

What is the recommended way to pass the authentication?

Comment: You must pass the `Authorization` request header such that `Authorization: Basic [base64_encode('username' + ':' + 'password')]`

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876777/set-http-header-for-one-request

Answer (score 0):

Second argument for the GET is the header part. For ex.

```
$http.get('www.google.com/someapi', {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}
}).then()..;
```

Answer (score 0):

the recommended method is **http-interceptors**.
what interceptor do, you can assume its a hook which call on every api request and response, once you write it, it will automatically add token in every api request. below is the url you read the article.

[Angular Authentication: Using the Http Client and Http Interceptors](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)